# Is the classifying space of a group infinite-dimensional?

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, classifying-spaces

According to the textbook by Allen Hatcher, the classifying space B$\mathscr{C}$ of a category ${\mathscr C}$ is constituted with a set of simplices of which $n$-simplices are the strings of morphisms. Since a group  $G$ can be taken as the set of morphisms of a category $\mathscr{C}$ with a single object, the textbook states that for this category, B$G$=B$\mathscr{C}$. Due to the definition of classifying spaces of categories, B$\mathscr{C}$ should be always infinite-dimensional. However, I saw on other materials, B$\mathbb{Z}=S^1$ which is only one-dimensional. Are the definitions different somewhere?

Comment: I think you can interpret this as "$B\Bbb Z$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$".

Comment: (and dimension is very much not a homotopy invariant)

Comment: Thanks! It should be understood in a homotopy-class sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a group is finite, any CW model of its classifying space must be infinite dimensional: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/64688/non-vanishing-of-group-cohomology-in-sufficiently-high-degree/64702#64702